# How can I disable and/or uninstall "Messages" from OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, applications, messages

This "Messages" application on my Macbook Pro, OS X Yosemite 10.10.4

I would like to uninstall the "Messages" application entirely. How can I do this?

Comment: Similar situation covered by [this answer.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/25499/120171)

Comment: I WANT TO DELETE THE MESSAGES APP. I WANT TO DELETE THE MESSAGES APP. omg apple really pissed me off this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Apple stock OS X apps cannot be deleted, you can remove the your Apple ID's association with the Messages app by opening Messages and clicking Messages > Preferences > Accounts.

From there you can remove your Apple ID (and therefore the phone numbers associated with it) and your problem should stop.

Comment: I already removed my Apple ID (well it's still there but greyed out saying "inactive". But the app still opens when I receive a message on my phone.

Comment: this "fix" is temporary. i keep getting prompted to log back in when i get messages. even after logging out, the iMessage seems to be in some sort of sync with the phone and keeps popping up. i've been wrestling with this issue for years.

Comment: In Catalina, you can uncheck the box enabling the apple id account.

Comment: I WANT TO DELETE THE MESSAGES APP. I WANT TO DELETE THE MESSAGES APP. omg apple really pissed me off this time.